# Change the area of the mask on mask R-CNN

Tags: deep-learning, python-3.7

i made a model which predict the area of the pants on image_1 and the area of the legs (avatar legs) i get the two masks but i now i want to cut the area of pants from image_1 and put the pants on the area of the legs on the avatar image .

1- crop the pants from image_1
2- put the cropped image on the mask of the legs.

Any one can help me please ?

Comment: In the return of the mask R-CNN don't you get the bounding box coordinates?

Comment: yes i get the bounding box but i don't know to to get the coordinates of the Bounding Box

Comment: Probably the return of your NN is a binary classification (pants, no pants) and the BB coordinates. If it's that, the BB coordinates are the position 2 to 5 of your returned vector. Is that clear?

Comment: not clear at all , my 1st NN is binary and also the 2nd NN get the legs of the avatar after get the mask and the BB of the legs i want to put the 1st NN mask on the 2nd NN images on the mask location . i didn't understand 2 of 5 of returned vector .

Comment: I don't understand, your first NN is only a binary classificator that say if there is a pant or not?

Comment: Note: i don't want to put the pants image on the bounding box of the 2nd NN , i want to put the pants image(mask) on the mask of the 2nd NN

Comment: yes and the 2nd NN is to get mask of the legs of the avatar

Comment: So you need to your first NN give you the BB with the mask, don't? How do you know where is the mask in the first NN?

Comment: pantalon_mask = pantalon_r['masks']
pantalon_mask = pantalon_mask.astype(int)
print(pantalon_mask.shape)
for i in range(pantalon_mask.shape[2]):
    temp2 = PANTALON
    for j in range(temp2.shape[2]):
        temp2[:,:,j] = temp2[:,:,j] * pantalon_mask[:,:,i]
    plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
    plt.imshow(temp2)
plt.show()